# python: print a TLV value from packet as a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, netlink, tlv

I'm reading data over `netlink` socket. One of the `TLVs` contain IPv4 address as a sequence of 4 bytes, e.g. `0x01 0x02 0x03 0x0b` for address `1.2.3.11` :

```
import socket
...
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_NETLINK, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.NETLINK_ROUTE)
s.bind((os.getpid(), RTMGRP_IPV4_IFADDR))

while True:
   data = s.recv(65535)
   msg_len, msg_type, flags, seq, pid = struct.unpack("=LHHLL", data[:16])
   ...

   # skip all headers and get to TLVs
   data = data[24:]
   remaining = msg_len - 24

   while remaining:
     rta_len, rta_type = struct.unpack("=HH", data[:4])
     ...
     rta_data = data[4:rta_len]

     ...
     if rta_type == IFA_ADDRESS:
         # rta_data[:4] contains IP address
     ...
```

I need to read `rta_data[:4]` in such way that I get a string which I can pass on further. I tried to play with `encode()` or `decode()` string methods, but with no luck. I guess I should be walking through `rta_data` and convert each byte into string and put dots in between? I wonder if there is a one-liner for this.

Comment: [socket.inet_ntoa](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.inet_ntoa) should do the thing.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, thanks much, that was it!